# Explicit specialization after instantiation in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I have some c++ code like that

head file a.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
template <class Real>
class GridGraph2
        {
                protected:
                class Vertex
                {
                    void SetWeight (int iDX, int iDY, Real fWeight)
                    {
                        m_afWeight[GridGraph2<Real>::ms_aaiIndex[iDY+1][iDX+1]] = fWeight;
                    }

                    Real GetWeight (int iDX, int iDY) const
                    {
                        return m_afWeight[GridGraph2<Real>::ms_aaiIndex[iDY+1][iDX+1]];
                    }
                    private:
                    Real m_afWeight[8];
                };
                friend class Vertex;
                static const int ms_aaiIndex[3][3];  // index[dy][dx]
        };
typedef GridGraph2<float> GridGraph2f;
#endif
```

code file a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
template
class GridGraph2<float>;

template<>
const int GridGraph2<float>::ms_aaiIndex[3][3] =
        {
                {0,1,2}, {3,-1,4}, {5,6,7}
        };
```

However, when I try to build in clion, I get some error:
`error: explicit specialization of 'ms_aaiIndex' after instantiation
    const int GridGraph2<float>::ms_aaiIndex[3][3] =
implicit instantiation first required here
                            m_afWeight[GridGraph2<Real>::ms_aaiIndex[iDY+1][iDX+1]] = fWeight;`

I want to know where should I modify that the code can be built successfuly and why the complier say `ms_aaiIndex` explicit specialization after instantiation.

I used xcode command tool to build it. But there is no errors when I use mingw to build it in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "a.h"
/*
 * remove this
 *
template
class GridGraph2<float>;
 *
 */

template<>
const int GridGraph2<float>::ms_aaiIndex[3][3] =
        {
                {0,1,2}, {3,-1,4}, {5,6,7}
        };
```

Comment: How to do it without a class name, seems not working for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "without a class name"?

Comment: Hi, I am talking about the templated function which didn't belong to a class or namespace.